# How to convert time format in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a timestamp type, like `x = 2020.01.24`, how to covert it to format in "24-01-2020" in DolphinDB? Currently I have to use string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `format` function to format the date.

```
x= 2020.01.24
format(x, "dd-MM-yyyy")
```